# Viewer app developed with PHP and supported file types

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are interested in developing a viewer like this: https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview

Is there an example like this available but with PHP?

On the other hand, does it support .rfa and .dwg files?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial [Learn Forge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/), you will learn how to use **Forge APIs** and there is many languages examples : NodeJS, .Net, Java, Go and **PHP**

As described in the documentation [Supported translations](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/):

- `.rfa` files are not supported (but there is various way to use these files with **Forge**)
- `.dwg` are supported.